# Unknown string when launching Doctrine command

Tags: macos, symfony, doctrine

When I launch the `schema:update --force` command in terminal, I got this strange output:

> Mac OS X 2??ATTR???xThis resource fork intentionally left blank   ?? Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.

Does anyone know from where the fist part of the message comes from?
Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue suddenly: Mac OS X         2??ATTR?p????*?*$com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTagsbplist00?   This resource fork intentionally left blank   ??

Comment: Try to delete from your project the files starting with: "._.DS_Store". This is how I solved.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution but that did not work for me. I've removed all ._.DS_Store and .DS_Store files but I still get the stange output.